# Two nanoparticle linear polarizers in series synchronously rotated?

Tags: optics

My question is in regards to what happens when you send polarized light through two nanoparticle linear polarizers in series and rotate them (together) from $0^\circ$ degrees to $180^\circ$. As far as Malus' Law goes, would you simply square $I = I_0 \cos^2(\theta)$?

However, due to some attenuation of the transmitted light, Io would have to change right? Would it be a difference equation such that Io is not the same as the transmitted light after the second polarizer? Also, the angle would change as well?

If the angle changes, why does this happen? I'm new to the field of optics so excuse my ignorance. Thank you for any information you may have in regards.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the polarizers are perfect linear polarizers and that the light before the first polarizer is randomly polarized, the first polarizer would reject some of the light and *output* only light that is 100 percent polarized in the direction determined by the polarizer's orientation.  Further assuming that the second polarizer is oriented to output 100 percent of the light output by the first polarizer,  the second polarizer would have no effect.  Rotate the two polarizers together, and the polarization of the output light would rotate with the polarizers.

Comment: The polarizer does NOT only transmit light 100% in the direction of the polarization axis.  It transmits light according to Quantum Mechanics where any light beam with any fraction of a component in the direction of the polarizer has a chance (or probability ) of being transmitted, the more oriented in the correct direction the higher the probability. This is why we get net 50% transmission for the randomly polarized light, if only 100% polarized in the direction was transmitted this would be a very low transmission.

Comment: Not sure I understand your objection, but I'm guessing it can be traced to one word (transmit), so I've edited accordingly, changing "transmit" to "output".

Comment: Yes that must have been it, the light (photons) before the polarizer has many x,y components and the bigger the x component the higher the probability of transmission (assuming the polarizer is oriented for x).

Answer (score 0):

2 polarizers in series or in sync as you suggest would decrease the intensity by the square of the transmittance ratio, i.e. 90% squared is 81% transmission.  Note that this is only for the 0 and 180 degree positions. At 90 you must square the extinction ratio number.